# Ignore SEO friendly URL Parameters in Google Analytics (or treat as query string)

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site structured as such

- www.example.com/en-us/index.html
- www.example.com/es-es/index.html

Although I have canonical links set up and google is indexing them correctly, google analytics is treating them as separate pages.

How do I set it up so that it treats them as the same page?

Answer (score 1):

They are separate pages - the client is using a different request URI for each. Canonical links simply indicate the *content* has been duplicated.

In order to get Analytics to treat them as the same, you'll have to rewrite the URI for the records. Pick the one you'd like to appear and create a custom filter in Analytics. Use Search and Replace on the Request URI.
[image: google analytics search and replace]